# org.hamcrest.Matcher's method equalTo() returning value like this <<value>>

Tags: java, automated-tests, assertj, springmockito

I am working on spring 5.0.7 project where I have some testcases which are getting fails which was working fine with previous version of spring.

when I am executing following statement

```
assertEquals("My message",401, equalTo(401));
```

getting following error message
[image]

There is additional <> comes in result. Can anyone has idea how can I fix it?

For more details earlier I was using assertThat()

```
 assertThat(401, equalTo(401));
```

and this was working fine.

Comment: With `assertEquals`, you're testing if two objects are equal. They are obviously not equal because they are different classes: the first is an Integer and the second is a Matcher.

Answer (score 1):

I revert back to assertThat() and that is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

if you are a bit confused with hamcrest, you can give a try to AssertJ whose assertions are easy to discover with code completion.

```
assertThat(401).isEqualTo(401);
               ^                       
              use code completion
```

Answer (score 0):

[`equalTo`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#equalTo(T)) returns a `Matcher` object which is not equal to an integer value, hence the `AssertionError`. `<401>` is just a string representation of a matcher.

With `assertEquals`, you're expected to pass the expected value directly, without a matcher:

```
assertEquals("My message", 401, 401);
```

Note that the first argument is the expected value.